# Blank Toolbar when scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, toolbar

My app has a Toolbar that hides when you scroll down the screen and appears when you start scrolling up.

In Lollipop it works perfectly, but in Kitkat a blank toolbar is sometimes shown when you scroll up. When you scroll a bit down again, the toolbar shows the correct content.

Am I missing something?

Here is part of my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".main.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Card Name"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

...

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a blank view below your `Toolbar` before the `AppBarLayout` closing statement.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".main.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Card Name"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>   

<View
        android:id="@+id/appbar_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

...

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```